# Unity, How do I get the world coordinates of corners of far clip panel of camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, pixel

I have undersood how to get the coordinates of the center of this rectangle. Also I know that ratio of its sides can be found using Camera.pixelRect. Property "Field of view" also changes the size (but not the ratio of the sides) of this rectangle. So how to get the length of the rectangle's sides in units?
[visual explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktlHM.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to get the width and height of your camera.

If you're using an orthographic camera, you can find its width and height using its [Camera.orthographicSize](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-orthographicSize.html) and [Camera.aspect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-aspect.html) values.

The camera's height is twice its orthographic size; you can find its width by multiplying its height by its aspect:

```
Camera cam = Camera.main;
float height = 2f * cam.orthographicSize;
float width = height * cam.aspect;
```